# What's a nice way to create a new vector by consuming two vectors?

Tags: vector, rust

I would like a nice function to create a new vector, and to communicate that the argument vectors are no longer relevant and should be destroyed, take ownership of them. I don't particularly want to have to make either of the arguments mutable (to use `append`, `extend`, or `push_all` and thus change the calling signature). Code ([playpen link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed449322da331139d5b3&version=stable)):

```
fn main () {
    let arg1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let arg2 = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let desired = consume_and_concat(arg1, arg2);
    assert_eq!(desired, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
}

fn consume_and_concat(vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    // something nice here
}
```

I know there's no `+` for `Vec`s. In Ruby, I'd do `vec1 + vec2` or `vec1.concat(vec2)` or `[vec1, vec2].flatten`. Is there something similarly elegant that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Extend::extend`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#method.extend)

```
fn main() {
    let mut arg1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let arg2 = vec![4, 5, 6];
    arg1.extend(arg2);
    assert_eq!(arg1, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Here, we are able to reuse the allocated space from `arg1`, but there's nothing to be done efficiently with the space allocated via `arg2`. For an example that is more specific to your original question:

```
fn main() {
    let arg1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let arg2 = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let desired = consume_and_concat(arg1, arg2);
    assert_eq!(desired, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
}

fn consume_and_concat(mut vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec1.extend(vec2);
    vec1
}
```

Comment: Ah. I thought I would have to add `mut` so that the caller would be `consume_and_concat(mut arg1, arg2)`. So I guess this is okay... it does bother me that `extend` doesn't return `self` so that it's chainable and could be returned directly...

Comment: There's also (unstable) [`append`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) which is designed to allow data structures (several implement it) to take advantage of their own internal invariants to be more efficient, e.g. `Vec::append` can just be a `memcpy`.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out that marking an argument `mut` in the signature is unnecessary; it's just a shortcut.

Thus, we can achieve the desired result without modifying the signature:

```
fn consume_and_concat(vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec1 = vec1;
    vec1.extend(vec2);
    vec1
}
```

And because we reuse `vec1` internal buffer, it's nearly as efficient as it gets (for better efficiency, checking the capacity of *both* `vec1` and `vec2` might lead to better result).

Of course, the shortcut:

```
fn consume_and_concat(mut vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec1.extend(vec2);
    vec1
}
```

is, well, shorter, and as you already realized, the fact that `vec1` is `mut` does not change the type of its argument and thus does not change how to pass arguments.

Comment: "I would like to point out that marking an argument mut in the signature is unnecessary; it's just a shortcut." → This is because mutability is a property of the stack location, not the owned objects. When moving into another location, the owned data can become mutable.

Comment: One thing that was pointed out to me recently is that the `mut` keyword in a function argument doesn't show up in rustdoc, so it really is an internal implementation detail. Since learning that, I'm much more likely to use it.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Oh nice! Thanks for publicizing this!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need either of them to be mutable, though if one was you would save a bit on reallocation. With Rust, one of the nice things is that you don't have to say that it consumes it. You can tell that just from the function signature. Since it doesn't take a reference, that means that the function is taking ownership.

```
fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let vec2 = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let concatenated_vecs = consume_and_concat(vec1, vec2);
    for num in concatenated_vecs {
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}

fn consume_and_concat(vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut result : Vec<i32> = vec![];
    result.extend(vec1);
    result.extend(vec2);
    result
}
```

Comment: I think that this answer is less elegant as you throw away the allocated space of `vec1`, *forcing* a reallocation and copy of those contents.

Comment: Yes, I understand ownership and consumption. I was including those details to make it clear that I'm looking for solutions with the function signature `(vec1: Vec<i32>, vec2: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>` and not `(vec1: &Vec<i32>, vec2: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I agree. I wrote it that way to match the desired function signature.